# Who makes software validation? What are the steps of its?

Tags: validation, software-quality

Fill in the X,Y,Z please.

1. Software validation has X,Y,Z steps.
2. Client have to provide X,Y,Z to the developer before starting to write  software.
3. When software finished, validation completes with doing X,Y,Z    (sign, approval, test
   pictures, logs    etc.).

If we buy a general software like invoice management tool or SAP module which can modify/change for every customer, who should make the software validation?

Comment: That will depend greatly on the capabilities of the tool you purchase, if the tool doesn't do it and you are the developer then the answer is 'You'.

Comment: Why does this read like a homework test?  Is it an appropriate question for stackoverflow - i.e. is it programming related?  Does the "X,Y,Z" imply that you believe that there exactly three steps to each process!?  In all cases the answer will depend on your local quality process - whatever it says!  Buy SAP and your users will hate you! ;)

Comment: :) I don't know it is appropriate or not but if it is bad or meaningless i can fix however you like :) Local quality process is very short answer but if i developed and sold a program, how can i make its validation to every customers local quality process. We don't have Windows 7 validation according to our quality process.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You just don't claim that it is Windows 7 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you supply to a customer, you are reponsible for unless your contract of supply with them specifies otherwise. This is why software product EULAs are so long. Have a look at all of the exclusions.

There's a difference between Validation, Verification and Customer Acceptance Testing.

You'll find that a Customer will sign off a package as being Accepted after a period of acceptance testing, but that doesn't mean that they'll accept any bugs within the code. That is why you perform validation and verification testing.

If you're using a licenced SDK to produce a product and your customer is hit finacially due to bugs in your product then you'll need to prove that it isn't your code but the SDK suppliers code if you wish to avoid litigation. This is also why you have insurance.

*edit - added*

Remember also to only lay claim to anything that you can prove to be the case. Don't claim that your product is Windows 7 compliant or compatible unless you can prove that it is.

You only need to meet a customers quality standards if that is what you have commercially agreed to provide, although you'll find that every country stipulates that software must not be of a malicious or harmful nature and fit for purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty old question, but I have some experience in this field thus I think I can contribute.

I will describe the simplified process that it suitable for small and middle size companies

The process starts with SRS (Software Requirements Specification) and flowchart based on SRS. These are prepared by software dev team.

The SRS forwarded to validation team. They write STD (Software Test Description) accoriding to the SRS and start validation process accordingly

During the process they create a record log with screenshot, etc... At the end of the day the validation team writes STR (Software Test Record)

Both STD and STR are signed by the validator, IT Manager,  QA Manager and Doc Control